# android:error during creating Table in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created application in android in that I perform crud operation. In apps database file was created successfully but error during creating table and following is the Logcat error and database adapter class.

**Logcat error**

```
01-17 13:03:59.139: E/SQLiteLog(1036): (1) table timerecordsnew1 has no column named note
01-17 13:03:59.309: E/SQLiteDatabase(1036): Error inserting note=asdfsdfadf
01-17 13:03:59.309: E/SQLiteDatabase(1036): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table timerecordsnew1 has no column named note (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO timerecordsnew1(note) VALUES (?)
01-17 13:03:59.309: E/SQLiteDatabase(1036):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Following is my **database adapter class**

```
public class TimeTrackerAdapter {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "timetrackernew1.db";
    //Table
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "timerecordsnew1";

    //Table Column Variable
    public static final String TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME = "time";
    public static final String TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE = "note";

    private TimeTrackerOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDb;

    //Database creation sql statement
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +  
            TABLE_NAME + "(" + TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT " + TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT);";

    public TimeTrackerAdapter(Context context) {
        openHelper = new TimeTrackerOpenHelper(context);
        sqlDb = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //to insert data into database
    public void saveRecords(String t, String n) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE,t);
        contentValues.put(TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE, n);

        sqlDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
    //get fetch the all data
    public Cursor getAllRecords() {

        return sqlDb.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    }

    // inner class
    private class TimeTrackerOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("create statement"+SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
            try
            {
                db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

            }catch(SQLiteException sql)
            {
                sql.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

Please anybody help me solve this error.

Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma in your SQL between the two columns:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +  
        TABLE_NAME + "(" + TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT **,%Comma goes here%** " + TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT "`  ==  `TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT, "`

You forget "," char.

Next time read exceptions and look through your code more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing a comma in the `create table` DDL. (on the `TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME` column..

from:

```
   private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
           TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
           TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT " + 
           TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT);";
```

to

```
   private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = 
         "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
            TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT, " + 
            TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
        TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT " + TIMERECORDS_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT);";
```

you get "time TEXT note TEXT" without comma to separate them.

Sqlite doesn't detect it as a syntax error: it started as "untyped" database, then added support for *type affinity*, but continued to allow all kind of junk for column type specification.